# Is every triangulation the projection of a convex hull

Tags: discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangulations

**Question:**

given the triangulation $T$ of a set $P$ of $n$ points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ in the euclidean plane whose convex hull is a triangle, can we always find a set $Q$ of $n+1$ points $q_0,q_1,\dots,q_n$ in euclidean 3-space such that:

- the points of $Q$ are in strictly convex configuration
- $q_0$ has the unique highest z-coordinate; that coordinate may also be $\infty$ in order to allow for orthogonal projections.
- $T$ is the projection of the skeleton of $Q\setminus q_0$'s convex hull into he euclidean plane provided $q_0$ is the center of projection?

Bonus question: provided existence and uniqueness, how can $Q$ be constructed from $T$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking whether every triangulation is a [regular triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_triangulation#Regular_triangulations). The answer is **no**. A common example of a non-regular triangulation is this:

[image]

Comment: Credit: I got this image (but not the example - it is well-known) from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740053/showing-triangulation-of-equilateral-triangle-is-non-regular

Comment: I'm not sure whether the "lifting", i.e. adding a coordinate really covers what I am asking for; in my setting also points on the upper part of the convex hull contribute to the skeleton and further the x and y coordinates of related $p_i$ and $q_i$ may be different. I'll have to check the exact meaning of lifting and whether my setting is equivalent to that of a lifting